# Copy a part of the character array to a wxString in c++

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, wxstring

I have an array of char like this:

```
char aData[100];
```

How can I copy only a part of aData from index *from* to index *to* in a wxString ?

Is it possible to make, with a wxString as destination and an array of char as source, something like memcpy in C ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this using the constructor that takes the number of byts to read.

```
wxString w(aData+from, to-from);
```

for an already existing `w`, you could say

```
w.assign(aData+from, to-from);
```

or you could use the iterator version:

```
w.assign(aData+from, aData+to);
```

Comment: Notice that this only works if `aData` uses the current locale encoding. E.g. if the encoding is UTF-8, as is typical under Unix, but `aData` is not a valid UTF-8 string, construction/assignment will fail.

Comment: @VZ what can I use in this case ?

Comment: If the data is in UTF-8, use `wxString::FromUTF8()`. Otherwise use the same ctor as in the answer, but with the extra `wxMBConv` parameter corresponding to the actual encoding.